# I keep getting the same value for two different intent extras

Tags: android, android-intent

I've been trying to pass extras via an intent from one activity to another.

```
//Create intent to send values to Menu//

Intent intent_to_Menu = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);

//get editText field values//

EditText first_edit_text   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
first = first_edit_text.getText().toString();
intent_to_Menu.putExtra (FIRST_EXTRA,first);

EditText middle_edit_text   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.middle_name);
middle = middle_edit_text.getText().toString();
intent_to_Menu.putExtra (MIDDLE_EXTRA,middle);

startActivity(intent_to_Menu);
```

Then receiving and displaying in the other activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
first = intent.getStringExtra(VerifyActivity.FIRST_EXTRA);
middle = intent.getStringExtra(VerifyActivity.MIDDLE_EXTRA);

TextView firstTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
firstTV.setText(first);
TextView lastTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
lastTV.setText(last);
```

At this point both textviews display the same value.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are FIRST_EXTRA and MIDDLE_EXTRA defined?

Comment: Make sure FIRST_EXTRA and MIDDLE_EXTRA are not the same. If they are, you will get the same result.

Comment: In the lastTV textview you are setting the value from a variable **last**, how is this variable initialized. Can you verify if your intention was to set the textview with **middle** and not **last**.

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved. I had initialized them as the same value. Silly mistake!